# How to escape single quotes in Unload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift-spectrum

```
    conn_string = "dbname='{}' port='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'"\
            .format(dbname,port,user,password,host_url) 

    sql="""UNLOAD ('select col1,col2 from %s.visitation_hourly_summary_us where col4= '2018-07-10' and col5= '1';') TO 's3://%s/%s/%s.csv' \
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s' \
            MANIFEST GZIP ALLOWOVERWRITE;Commit;""" \
            % (schema_name,s3_bucket_name, schema,table,aws_access_key_id,\
            aws_secret_access_key)

con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
```

I'm trying to execute the above script to read the table and then create a file in S3

Since my columns are string I'm not able to skip the single quotes and I'm getting error as syntax error near where

Also, I've tried giving \ in where condition still it showing the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you are getting? in my opinion your `conn_string` is wrong here

Comment: Also, do *not* use string formatting operations to build a query. Pass a parameterized query and a tuple of arguments separately to `execute` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sarang says, simply by replacing single quotes by double quotes in col4 and col5 values of your query should do the trick.

However I would suggest you to break your string down in smaller chunks easier to read and maintain. This way, you should be able to use `execute` as chepner suggests (and [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)):

```
# Create the inner SQL statement. Notice the single quotes for the general
# string and the double quotes for the col4 and col5 values
sql_stmt = ('SELECT col1, col2 '
            'FROM %s.visitation_hourly_summary_us '
            'WHERE col4 = "2018-07-10" AND col5= "1";' % schema_name)

# Format the s3 path
s3_target = 's3://%s/%s/%s.csv' % (s3_bucket_name, schema, table)

# Format credentials string
s3_credentials = 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s' % (
    aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)

# Create a tuple with all preformatted strings
data = (sql_stmt, s3_target, s3_credentials)

# Format the s3 query skeleton
s3_stmt = ("UNLOAD ('%s') TO '%s' "
           "CREDENTIALS '%s' "
           "MANIFEST GZIP ALLOWOVERWRITE;Commit;")

con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(s3_stmt, data)
```

Answer (score 26):

You can also use postgres style :

```
unload 
($$
select * from table where id='ABC'
$$)
to 's3://bucket/queries_results/20150324/table_dump/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
;
```

Comment: This approach lets you have syntax highlighting for the query.

Comment: This approach avoids escaping character hell, thanks !

Answer (score 9):

You would want to use two single quotes to enclose the value.

> If your query contains quotes (for example to enclose literal values),
>   put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must
>   also enclose the query between single quotation marks:

Example:

```
UNLOAD ('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')
```

Taken from the redshift documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Answer (score 1):

' (single quotes can be sent as ) ->    \\\\'

I had used this in the R as well as python
Please find solutions

if your sql QUERY is

**Select * from sample_table where register_date='2018-12-31'**

then for unload command write it like this

```
sql=     """unload ('Select * from tnltemp.otpsuccess_details where register_date=\\\\'2018-12-31\\\\' ')
        to 's3://my-bucket/migration/exported_sample_table_' credentials 
        'aws_access_key_id=12234123;aws_secret_access_key=12345'
        DELIMITER AS ','
        NULL AS ''
        parallel off;""""



cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put values in double quotes.
'select col1,col2 from %s.visitation_hourly_summary_us where col4= "2018-07-10" and col5= "1";'